# Prevent fom submit and call Bootstrap dialog

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this simple example of form and Bootstrap dialog:

```
  <form data-form-output="form-output-global" data-form-type="contact">
        <div class="text-center text-lg-left offset-top-20">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demoModal">Buy</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sell</button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="demoModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="section-60 offset-top-35">

                  <div class="offset-top-20 text-md-center">
                    <h6>Request to enable demo mode is send for approval.</h6>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I want to perform some logical check and if the code does not match the criteria to display the dialog window and prevent form submit. How I can implement this?

Comment: Means, you need to show modal if a condition is not satisfied and trigger submit when the condition is satisfied?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Please see my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly submitting the form. First you need to check your condition if condition is true then go ahead and submit your form. But if the condition is false then show the modal popup.

```js
$("button.btn").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var test = 6;
 if(test != 5){
  $("#demoModal").modal();
 } else {
  $("#myform").submit();
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
   <form id="myform" data-form-output="form-output-global" data-form-type="contact">
                                        <div class="text-center text-lg-left offset-top-20">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sell</button>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="modal fade" id="demoModal" role="dialog">
                                          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                              <div class="container">
                                                <div class="section-60 offset-top-35">

                                                  <div class="offset-top-20 text-md-center">
                                                    <h6>Request to enable demo mode is send for approval.</h6>
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
  
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just for information is there some alternative approach without JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry @PeterPenzov, not in my knowledge.